# BIOS won't recognize my USB.

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, usb, bios

Here's my situation: Couple months ago I installed Ubuntu and now I want to install Windows 7 on my computer (for nostalgia's sake). Problem is the Bios won't recognize my USB stick so there's no way I can start the installation via my usb.

Is it because the installation is on an NTFS filesystem USB stick and so Ubuntu won't recognize it?

I've done some research on it and some forums suggest to use Plop to force the boot, but I don't have a floppy/LiveCD available to me right now to install Plop.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Do you have access to another Windows system? You could try and make a bootable USB there with something like Rufus, it will also format the USB stick in the right format. The USB not booting shouldn't have to do anything with Linux since the USB starts before Linux does.

Comment: @JustDenDimi I did the bootable usb on my laptop which still has windows on it. I simply downloaded the windows iso and used the official microsoft usb tool to make the bootable usb. So basically, it should be bootable. But I can't find it in the bios of my pc.

Comment: Did you try to format your stick with FAT32?

Comment: @AliChen How do I do that?

Comment: @AliChen I tried it right now. Didn't work out.

Comment: How many different USB sticks did you try?

Comment: @AliChen So far 2. It may be worth noting that tried creating the bootable USB on ubuntu by using Gparted and UNetbootin and then with Windows.

Comment: Does your BIOS recognize **ANY** USB pen drives, other than the two which were first screwed with Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Have been facing such situation a few times with older 7-9yrs BIOS'es, e.g. Phoenix.

The trick I found on some of them was, to exclude (marking the row and clicking x on keyboard, or alike) some of the unused boot devices from the list and a new one did fit-in and pop-up there instead.

Please, a new comment to @AliChen comment (sorry, do not yet have the right to comment directly):
The format FAT32 can be choosen e.g. on Rufus v2.10 .

Comment: My experience is that if a flash drive was touched by Linux, then its boot sector gets somehow contaminated, and UEFI/BIOS may not like it. I would get a fresh off-shelf flash drive, and format it to FAT32 under WINDOWS. There are some Linux tools that allow to really clean up a USB drive, so Linux experts should help here.

Comment: @AliChen OK, yes, the tool for cleaning up etc. a USB drive in Windows is named -> diskpart with commands list disk, select disk, clean, and list partition, a.s.o., examples in here -> http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN153364/en  .

Answer (score 0):

> the BIOS won't recognize my USB stick ...
>   Is it because the installation is on an NTFS filesystem USB stick and
>   Ubuntu won't recognize it?

No, mainly because the firmware  (BIOS, UEFI, coreboot, ...) starts well before it gets to Ubuntu.  (And secondly Ubuntu can recognise NTFS).

> Does anyone have a solution to this?

Some **old** BIOS's have a known bug where they do not add devices to the bootable list unless they were inserted prior to booting. In other words, turn the PC off, insert the USB pendrive, power on and try booting from it.

Another potential issue is on more modern computers. These often support booting from USB<1|2>, but not from USB3. Make sure you insert the installation USB pendrive into an USB2 port.

Two notes ont hat:

1. If you have no USB3 ports then this obviously is not the case.
2. If you do and it is in an UISB3 port then windows 7 setup would fail anyway unless you added the right drivers. THis because windows 7 does not ship with any USB3 drivers in its isos.

And lastly but certainly not least. Many motherboard have options for USB legacy mode. Toggle that one and try again.

Comment: My computer is relatively new (like 2 years old). And I do have both USB3 and regular USB slots available on my computer and I tried everywhich possible. I also tried your first suggestion (turning my pc off first and then putting the usb in) just in case, but it didn't work out. On the list of bootable devices it's still only ubuntu.

Comment: Since it is relave new: Does it have BIOS firmware or UEFI firmware? And if UEFI, how is the pendrive formatted? FAT32 and the boot.efi file in the relavant place? (UEFI will not boot from NTFS pendrives nor  from pendrives with a MBR bootsector inless you have backward crompatability turned on).

Comment: You're talking with someone who doesn't know much about technological stuff (yet!).  But when I get into my BIOS I do see something EFI on it, if that's any helpful.

Comment: If you wsee somethign with EFI on it then you have no BIOS. Motherboard firmware come in a few flavours. One of them is BIOS, another is UEFI. An EFI BIOS is something which does not exits (though many people mistakenly call the firmware a BIOS, even though it is a BIOS without BIOS. Ugh!). Anyway. BIOS is a firmware from somewhere between 1980 and 1990. EFI is a properly defined standard. One which can boot from an EFI filesystem; and that EFI filesystem happens to be 100% compatible with FAT32. I looks for a file /EFI/boot.efi and not for a bootsector.

Answer (score 0):

Some motherbroad can only read data from fat32 or fat16 fs, so make sure your usb stick is fat32. Also, after change to fat32 if it still not work turn your stick into MBR partition table(for super old computer).
The install.wim/esd is too big so you can't put into fat32? Click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/split-a-windows-image--wim--file-to-span-across-multiple-dvds?view=windows-11#split-the-file) to split the image.
(ps: you may need to use school/work pc to split it because pretending you don't have windows now)
pps: if your bios doesn't boot from your usb use efi shell to boot or use csm.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some suggestions:

- Always use FAT32 on USB boot drives. Never NTFS. Don't use exFAT.
- Try to enable both CSM and UEFI in the BIOS.
- Try both Windows partition table and GPT partition table.
- Make sure the .iso fits. It is not possible to use a 64bit .iso on a 32bit PC for example.
- Try both "Windows 7 USB/DVD Download Tool" and rufus.
- Install VirtualBox and see if the .iso boots there. If not than something is wrong with the .iso file.
- Maybe use a USB CD drive. I always have one here if USB flash drive boot fails.
- Try disabling secure boot.
- It is possible that the USB drive is not in the BIOS boot order list. Make sure it appears there.
- Load BIOS default settings.

Good luck!